# what could be the reason for losing the service name in dbus

Tags: c++, linux, dbus

I am using c++ common-api dbus bindings. From client I am calling a method named getCurrentTrackInfo(struct trackInfo_st &trackInfo) in server.

This data structure has greater than 15 members.

When this particular method [getCurrentTrackInfo] is called, server is losing the bus name immediately. [com.service.MediaPlayerDemo]

Is there any list of do's & dont's or error codes in dbus for capturing the reason for losing the bus name.

Answer (score 2):

You can watch what goes on on the bus by using `dbus-monitor`, any errors should be visible.

I would try to interact with the service using another method to rule out errors in the binding and client code. One way could be to use e.g. `D-Feet` or `dbus-send` if you are on a linux machine.

If the error is due to the service crashing, which is what it sounds like, then the actual error will likely not be visible on the bus.

Comment: Since my service crashes, I am not able to see any thing in dbus-monitor log. In my data structure out of 20 elements 6 elements are string. For some set of string, dbus method call was fine and for some other set of strings, dbus method call fails with remote error in client side and service crashes in server side.

Comment: As I say in the answer, you can exclude the client side as error source by interacting with the service with e.g. D-Feet. If the service crashes anyway I'd say it's pretty clear that the error is within the service and there's nothing you can do in the client side to fix the error. In D-Bus there are no "Dont's" that you can do in your client to crash a service, if that happens then there is an error in the service.

Comment: Thanks. so I will rule out client part. Now I want to check server, any help on how to start debugging this in server would be a great help. I tried  using D-Feet its cool tool.

Comment: OK, great. The service should be debugged as any other piece of software. The crash doesn't necessarily have to do with D-Bus at all. I suggest you come up with a specific question for that problem and post another question on Stack Overflow about it. Good luck!